# Javascript .load function returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with the `.load` function or one of the other functions. I'm doing a `.change` then a `.load` for an HTML select, but every time it returns the select tag with `[]`. Here is a video on it.

http://gyazo.com/75a3f2b2da3f9f32b3943e512025e643

The Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ticket_dep").change(function(){
        $("#result").html('Retrieving ...');
        var selected = parseInt($('#ticket_dep').val());
        $("#result").load("<?=URL_CP?>includes/json.php?function=changeareaadmin",{'dep_id':selected});
    });
});
```

The HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-4" align="right">Assign Ticket</td>
    <td class="col-md-8">
    <form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the PHP code:

```
case "changeareaadmin":
    if(isset($_POST["dep_id"])) {

        $display = "<select name='ladder' class='form-control pull-left'><option>sssweewfeffe</option></select>";           
        echo $display;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Why did you tag this Java?  There's no Java here.

Comment: This isn't java. Java and javascript are completely different. Replace your `java` tag for `jQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function expects the server to return html but it appears that your server is returning json which I might expect from something called json.php.

Comment: Thank you.. Once I tested what you said it was the json array. So I just made a new file for these type of things. Now it working.